# How to get the PID of a node.js server

Tags: node.js, pid

Say you start up server using node.js

```
const http = require('http');
const serverPort = 8050;
http.createServer((Req, Res) => {
        runRequestHandler(Req, Res);
    }).listen(serverPort, () => {
        console.log("Server running on port " + serverPort);
    });
```

is there a way to get the PID of that server.  Is it the same as `require("process").pid`?

Comment: Your node script _is_ the server. So yes, it's just `process.pid` (no requiring anything, `process` is a global)

Comment: Thanks Mike, maybe add re-post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may access PID via `require("process").pid`, but `process` is also available in the global scope of your module in Node.js so `process.pid` also works fine.

Here is more info: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processpid

Comment: Lukasz, thanks for the correction.  I inadvertently confused the question with the "process" oversight.  The answer (see above, but in a comment by Mike Kamermans) is that `process.pid` IS the server's pid